# elementClick event is not firing in angular-nvd3 chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am using [Angular-nvd3](https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/) for drawing the pie chart.

**HTML**

```
<nvd3 options="options.chart.options" data="options.chart.data" api="options.chart.api" config="config" events="events"></nvd3>
```

[image]

**Javascript**

```
$scope.options.chart = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'pieChart',
            height: 500,
            margin: {
                top: 0,
                right: 40,
                bottom: 80,
                left: 40
            },
            x: function(d) {
                return d.key;
            },
            y: function(d) {
                return d.y;
            },
            showLabels: true,
            duration: 1500,
            labelThreshold: 0.01,
            showLegend: true,
            lines: {
                dispatch: {
                    elementClick: function(e) {
                        console.log('click')
                    },
                    elementMouseover: function(e) {
                        console.log('mouseover')
                    },
                    elementMouseout: function(e) {
                        console.log('mouseout')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    data: [{
        key: "One",
        y: 5
    }, {
        key: "Two",
        y: 2
    }, {
        key: "Three",
        y: 9
    }, {
        key: "Four",
        y: 7
    }, {
        key: "Five",
        y: 4
    }, {
        key: "Six",
        y: 3
    }, {
        key: "Seven",
        y: .5
    }],
    api: {}
};
```

I need to  call an event,when the user click on the pie chart.But  the above code is not working.Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are using third party library in angularjs in order satisfy your requirement, so any changes towards third party suppose to be reflect in your own scope so you should use $scope.$apply().

```
 elementClick: function(e) {
                    $scope.$apply();
                    console.log('click')
                }
```

I hope this would help you.:)

Answer (score 0):

I just replace this in your javascript code

```js
lines: {
    dispatch: {
        elementClick: function(e){
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log('click')
        },
        elementMouseover: function(e){
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log('mouseover')
        },
        elementMouseout: function(e){
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log('mouseout')
        }
    }
}
```

with

```js
pie: {
    dispatch: {
        elementClick: function(e){
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log('click')
        },
        elementMouseover: function(e){
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log('mouseover')
        },
        elementMouseout: function(e){
            $scope.$apply();
            console.log('mouseout')
        }
    }
}
```

then its working as you expected.
Reference URL : [write click event handle function on pieChart line](https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/436)